# How do I zip a Object stream in Java?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a `Object` as

```
private String name;
private int age;
private String country;
// getters and setters
```

I convert this object into `XML` using `JAXB` as following

```
OutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(getOutputFilePath(document.getUniqueId())));
write(proposal, stream);
```

and

```
protected void write(@Nonnull final Document document, @Nonnull final OutputStream stream) throws PersistenceException {
        try {
            jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(document, stream);
        } catch (final JAXBException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new PersistenceException("Failed to marshall document " + docment.getUniqueId() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

How can I convert this `stream` into Zip file on disk?

Comment: [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has a number of classes for dealing with compression in various ways. Here's a useful link: [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/)

Answer (score 0):

As has already been suggested, wrap your `ObjectStream` around a `ZipOutStream`

```
OutputStream stream = new ZipOutputStream(new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(getOutputFilePath(document.getUniqueId()))));
```